# Open Modal in App.js from a button in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have three components in my app.

> App.js
> HeroSection.js
> Modal.js

The button I have for opening the Modal is in HeroSection.  But I need the Modal to render from App.js due to how the styling is structured.  When it is opened from HeroSection, it opens in a container that doesn't allow me to position the Modal in the center of the screen (It's in a CSS grid set up).  I hope I'm making sense.

My code:

```js
const App = ({ signOut }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickOpenAccountModal} className='add-account'>Add Account</button>
            {openAddAccountModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenAddAccountModal} />}
            <div className="App">
                <div className='nav-pane'>
                    <SideBar signOut={signOut} />
                </div>
                <div className='content-pane'>
                    <MainContent />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```js
const HeroSection = () => {
    // Add Acount Button
    const [openAddAccountModal, setOpenAddAccountModal] = useState(false);
    const clickOpenAccountModal = () => {
        setOpenAddAccountModal(true);
    }

    // Add Transaction Button
    const [openAddTransactionModal, setOpenAddTransactionModal] = useState(false);
    const clickOpenTransactionModal = () => {
        setOpenAddTransactionModal(true);
    }

    return (
        <div className='hero-section'>
            <h1 className='page-title'>Users's Dashboard</h1>
            <div className='hero-buttons'>
                <button onClick={clickOpenAccountModal} className='add-account'>Add Account</button>
                {openAddAccountModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenAddAccountModal} />}
                <button onClick={clickOpenTransactionModal} className='add-transaction'>Add Transaction</button>
                {openAddTransactionModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenAddTransactionModal} />}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```js
const Modal = ({ closeModal }) => {
    return (
        <div className='modal-background'>
            <div className='modal-container'>
                <div className='title-container'>
                    <h2>Add Account</h2>
                    <button className='exit-button' onClick={() => closeModal(false)}>X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Main App
[image]

How the modal opens in HeroSection
[image]

How I need it to open from the button in HeroSection
[image]

I tried copying the logic for opening and closing the modal directly to App.js, but to get that to work, I had to put the button used to open the Modal in App.js as well.  I need the button to stay in HeroSection and render from App.js

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: looks like you are not using any UI library. Could you add your CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is more valid to put the button in the HeroSection component and let the modal be opened in the App.js component. So to start it's the correct approach.

For the implementation there are 2 options:

**1-**
If the application won't grow to much more components, you can still have the open modal button in the HeroSection component. And that `HeroSection` component can take a callback function as a prop (for ex `openModal`) which it can calls when the button is clicked. That way when the function runs you implement the logic for opening/closing the modal in the App.js.

[Check solution 1 in react codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5r0r7r?file=/index.js)

2-
If the application can grow to many components, solution 1 will create unmaintainable code in the long run.

To address this, you can start using a general state management library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

When you do that, you can open/close a modal from any component you want without passing any modal specific prop to that component

**In general applications, the more correct approach is solution 2. But it can be unnecessary complexity if the application only contains 3 component**